# How to create a boolean value?

Tags: xml, xslt, boolean, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am totally new to XSLT and can't work out where I am going wrong with the following code.

```
<xsl:variable name="var" select="boolean('false')"/>

<xsl:if test="$var'">variable is true</xsl:if>
```

It is always returning true when it is meant to be false. Why?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The value of the $var variable as defined in:

`<xsl:variable name="var" select="boolean('false')"/>`

is

**`true()`**

This is because in XPath "`false`" is an ordinary string, as opposed to `false()`, which is the constructor for the `boolean` value `false()`

**The two boolean values in XPath are** (note that they are constructed!):

**`true()`**  and  **`false()`**

The detail of converting any value to boolean are spelled outin the [XPath Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#section-Boolean-Functions).:

"The [**boolean**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-boolean) function converts its argument to a boolean as follows:

- a number is true if and only if it
  is neither positive or negative zero
  nor NaN
- a node-set is true if and only if it
  is non-empty
- a string is true if and only if its
  length is non-zero
- an object of a type other than the four basic types is converted to a boolean in a way that is dependent on that type
  "

In your case the string "false" is not the number 0 and has a positive length, so the rule in the 3rd bullet above is applied, yielding `true()`.

**Therefore, to define a variable in XSLT 1.0, whose value is** [**`false()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-false), one needs to write the definition as the following:

`<xsl:variable name="vMyVar" select="false()"/>`

or, if you don't exactly remember this, you could always write:

`<xsl:variable name="vMyVar" select="1 = 0"/>`

(specify any expression that evaluates to `false()`) and the XSLT processor will do the work for you.

**In XSLT 2.0 it is always better to explicitly specify the type** of the variable:

`<xsl:variable name="vMyVar" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>`

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Hi Dimitre. This is the solution if the boolean value is hardcoded in the XSL transformation file. Is there a neat solution for `false` and `true` strings coming from the file being under transformation that does not involve string comparision?

Comment: @Jagger, This is for another question. This question asks "*How to create a Boolean value*" and has got its precise answer. You are asking: "*How to interpret (or parse) particular strings into Boolean values*" -- this is a completely different question. May I ask what is wrong with string comparison?

Answer (score 18):

The boolean() function you are using is indeed doing it's job. For using explicit true and false values you should use the following functions:

```
<xsl:variable name="var_false" select="false()"/>
<xsl:variable name="var_true" select="true()"/>
```

Just FYI, per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256159(VS.85).aspx), boolean() returns the following:

- If the argument is a negative or positive number, it is converted to the Boolean value true.
- If the argument is zero or an NaN value, it is converted to false.
- If the argument is a non-empty node-set, it is converted to true. An empty node-set is converted to false.
- **If the argument is a non-empty string, it is converted to true**. An empty string is converted to false.
- If the argument is an object of a type other than the four basic types, it is converted to a Boolean in a way that is dependent on that type.

Comment: You should reformat the penultimate item of your list to stand out more, as it is the crucial one. "boolean('')" would produce false as well.

Comment: @Tomalak, see my answer. It is a little bit more detailed and quotes the true source: the W3C XPath Spec, rather than "MSDN".

Comment: @Dimitre: I don't think MSDN deviates too much from the W3C spec in this regard. :) But pointing *there* is of course more correct.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late at this stage perhaps but imo dealing with booleans is just not worth the effort. Heres how I dealt with a boolean (Mandatory) coming back from the DB:

```
<xsl:variable name="vTrue" select="true()"/>                     
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string(Mandatory) = string($vTrue)">
        <xsl:text>Mandatory</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>           
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Hope this helps someone