# xpath return all non-blank text nodes not descendant of `a`, `style` or `script`

Tags: xpath

What expression would select all text nodes which are:

- **not** blank
- **not** inside `a`, or `script` or `style`?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a shorter and significantly more efficient XPath expression than the currently accepted one. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do, assuming "not inside" means the text node is not supposed to be a descendant of an "a" or "script" or "style" element. If "not inside" only means not supposed to be a child then use parent::a and so on instead of ancestor::a.

```
//text()[normalize-space() and not(ancestor::a | ancestor::script | ancestor::style)]
```

Comment: Need one help from you - is there any difference between `/books/child::*` and `/books/child::node()` ?

Comment: Is it possible to have the condition //text()[not(ancestor::a)]  but allow some specific list of words? Like if the link is on the word "Home" then we keep it. Or is it totally absurd?

Answer (score 17):

**Use**:

```
//*[not(self::a or self::script or self::style)]/text()[normalize-space()]
```

**Not only is this expression shorter than the one in the currently accepted answer, but it also may be much more efficient**.

Do note that the expression doesnt use any (back/up)-ward axes at all.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Tested with firebug and it does shorten the time it takes to get the nodes.

Comment: @Majid: You are welcome. If this is better than the currently accepted answer, you may consider accepting my answer.

Comment: I would have, was it not rude to the other person who kindly answered my question.

Comment: sir what is `normalize-space()` doing in the nodetest ?

Comment: TLDR: doesn't select non-blank nodes.

The `normalize-space` function strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space

So this returns the empty string in the case where the node only has whitespace, which means the nodetest fails (empty strings being falsey: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346226/how-to-create-a-boolean-value) and the nodes containing only whitespace are omitted.

Answer (score 3):

I used Dimitre Novatchev's answer, but then i stumbled upon the problem described by the topic starter:

> not **descendant** of `a`, `style` or `script`

Dimitre's answer excludes `style` tag but includes its children.
This version excludes also `style`, `script`, `noscript` tags **and** their descendants:

```
//div[@id='???']//*[not(ancestor-or-self::script or ancestor-or-self::noscript or ancestor-or-self::style)]/text()
```

Anyway, thanks to Dimitre Novatchev.

Comment: +1 Haven't tried it, but from your description, this is a more robust method.

Comment: @warvariuc: Why do you think a `<style>` element can have (element) children? I searched for this -- here one can see that no such syntax is mentioned: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style