# How to parse the following html code get all text before "br" tag

Tags: xpath, html-parsing

I have the following html code:

```
    <td class="role" style=""><a href="/wiki/Chairman">Chairman</a> of <a href="/wiki/Microsoft">Microsoft</a><br />
    <a href="/wiki/Chairman">Chairman</a> of <a href="/wiki/Corbis">Corbis</a><br />
    Co-Chair of the <a href="/wiki/Bill_%26_Melinda_Gates_Foundation">Bill &amp; Melinda   Gates Foundation</a><br />
    <a href="/wiki/Creative_Director" title="Creative Director" class="mw- redirect">Director</a> of <a href="/wiki/Berkshire_Hathaway">Berkshire Hathaway</a><br/>
    <a href="/wiki/CEO" class="mw-redirect" title="CEO">CEO</a> of <a  href="/wiki/Cascade_Investment">Cascade Investment</a></td>
```

For the above td element, semantically there are five rows, separated by `"<br/>"`, I want to get the five lines as:

```
Chairman of Microsoft

Chariman of Borbis

Co-Char of the Bill&Melinda Gates Fundation

Creative Director of Berkshire Hathaway

CEO of Cascade Investment
```

Currently, my solution is to first get all `br` inside this `td`, as:

```
    br_value = td_node.select('.//br')
```

then for each br_value, I use the following code to get all text:

```
    for br_item in br_value:
        one_item = br_item.select('.//preceding-sibling::*/text()').extract()
```

In this case, I can get the line as:

```
Chairman Microsoft

Chariman Borbis

Bill&Melinda Gates Fundation

Director Berkshire Hathaway

CEO Cascade Investment
```

Compared with the original text I want, they basically missed "of", also some other texts.

The reason for this is that "preceding-sibling" only return the sibling tags, but can't return the "text" which belongs to its parent, such as "of" in this case.

Anyone here know how to extract the complete information separated by `br` tag?

Thanks

Comment: be so nice to vote and accept an answer, please

Answer (score 2):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378502/xpath-return-all-non-blank-text-nodes-not-descendant-of-a-style-or-script/6303276#6303276) xpath query:

`//div[@id='???']/descendant-or-self::*[not(ancestor-or-self::script or ancestor-or-self::noscript or ancestor-or-self::style)]/text()`

I.e. to select just text from current and all descendant nodes, use this kind of query: `./descendant-or-self::*/text()`

Or shorter (thanks to Empo): `.//text()`

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly I am looking for, descendant-or-self works perfectly.

Comment: The same can be obtained using `.//text()` which short for descendant. +1

Comment: yes, they are equivalent - just checked - thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this small function:

```
function getCleanLines($rawContent)
{
    $cleanLines = array();
    $regEx = '/<td\sclass="role"[^>]*>(?<CONTENT>.*?)<\/td>/ms';
    preg_match_all($regEx, $rawContent, $matches);

    if(isset($matches['CONTENT'][0]))
    {
        $content = $matches['CONTENT'][0];
        $regEx = '/(?<DATA>.*?)(?:<br\s*\/>|\z)/ms';
        preg_match_all($regEx, $content, $matchedLines);

        if(isset($matchedLines['DATA']))
        {
            foreach($matchedLines['DATA'] as $singleLine)
            {

                $regEx = '#(<a[^>]*>)|(</a>)#';
                $cleanLine = preg_replace($regEx,'',$singleLine);
                if(!empty($cleanLine))
                {
                    $cleanLines[] = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$cleanLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $cleanLines;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$input = 'HERE PUT YOUR HTML FROM PREVIOUS POST';
print_r(getCleanLines($input));
```

Comment: And :) Is that what you are looking for? :)

Comment: Thanks, maybe I didn't explain clearly, I am looking for the xpath solution Since the input html varies a lot in term of "sclass" name, etc. Another answer in this thread solved my problem perfectly. Anyway, thank you very much for your help ;-)