# Get text before or after html tags using Xpath

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have html which I am simplifying here, I need to write an xPath to get phone number.

```
<td>
    <font>
        <b>
            <font size="2">
                <a href="#">Some link</a>
            </font>
        </b>
        <br>
        Abc Address
        <br>
        Country name
        <br>
        (123) 456-7890
        <hr>
        A sentence here..
        <img src="/images/abc.gif">
    </font>
</td>
```

I can extract text inside anchor tag as,

```
->filterXPath('//font//b//a')->extract('_text'); //returns some link
```

How do I extract this text **(123) 456-7890** after last `<br>` tag or before first `<hr>` tag? I have visited [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289376/how-to-parse-the-following-html-code-get-all-text-before-br-tag), but I couldn't understand properly.

I have also tried this:

```
->filterXPath('//font//br[last()]')->extract('_text'); // returns nothing but empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the last `br`, then its first text sibling:

```
//font/br[last()]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Comment: Oh My God, I must have thank you in a special way @choraba, you are life saver. It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot !