# HTML XPath: Extracting text mixed in with multiple tags?

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

Goal: Extract text from a particular element (e.g. li), while ignoring the various mixed in tags, i.e. flatten the first-level child and simply return the concatenated text of each flattened child separately.

Example:

```
<div id="mw-content-text"><h2><span class="mw-headline" >CIA</span></h2>
    <ol>
    <li>Central <a href="/Intelligence_Agency.html">Intelligence Agency</a>.</li>
    <li>Culinary <a href="/Institute.html">Institute</a> of <a href="/America.html">America</a>.</li>
    </ol>

    </Div>
```

desired text:

- Central Intelligence Agency
- Culinary Institute of America

Except that the anchor tags surrounding prevent a simple retrieval.

To return each li tag separately, we use the straightforward:

```
//div[contains(@id,"mw-content-text")]/ol/li
```

but that also includes surrounding anchor tags, etc. And

```
//div[contains(@id,"mw-content-text")]/ol/li/text()
```

returns only the text elements that are direct children of li, i.e. 'Central','.'...

It seemed logical then to look for text elements of self and descendants

```
//div[contains(@id,"mw-content-text")]/ol/li[descendant-or-self::text]
```

but that returns nothing at all!

Any suggestions? I'm using Python, so I'm open to using other modules for post-processing.

(I am using the Scrapy HtmlXPathSelector which seems XPath 1.0 compliant)

Comment: May be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378502/xpath-return-all-non-blank-text-nodes-not-descendant-of-a-style-or-script/6303276

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**You were almost there. There is a small problem in**:

```sh
//div[contains(@id,"mw-content-text")]/ol/li[descendant-or-self::text]
```

**The corrected expression is**:

```sh
//div[contains(@id,"mw-content-text")]/ol/li[descendant-or-self::text()]
```

**However, there is a simpler expression that produces exactly the wanted concatenation of all text-nodes under the specified `li`:**

```sh
string(//div[contains(@id,"mw-content-text")]/ol/li)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why `contains` is used instead of `@id=` or is it just because the OP asked the question with `contains`?

Comment: @Lirik, With this answer I help the OP to get his code doing what he wants -- I can't guess whether he wants to select a `div` with exactly that `id` attribute, or with an `id` attribute that contains a given string. It is likely he meant the former, but an answerer should avoid making guesses, whenever possible.

Answer (score 5):

I think the following would return the correct result:

```
//div[contains(@id,"mw-content-text")]/ol/li//text()
```

Note the double slash before text(). This means text nodes on any level below li must be returned.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it returns all text elements, without any context of which li they came from. Checking with Firefox's 'XPath Checker' I get:
1: Central
2: Intelligence Agency
3: .
4: Culinary
5: Institute
6: of
7: America
8: .

There's no way to know which text came from which li...

Comment: If each line ends with a period (and there are no lines with periods in between (like Dr., Mr., etc.)), you can concatenate all text up to the period and just assume that each period == the end of an li.

Answer (score 2):

The string concatenation is tricky. Here's a quick solution using `lxml`:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.HTML("""<div id="mw-content-text"><h2><span class="mw-headline" >CIA</span></h2>
...     <ol>
...     <li>Central <a href="/Intelligence_Agency.html">Intelligence Agency</a>.</li>
...     <li>Culinary <a href="/Institute.html">Institute</a> of <a href="/America.html">America</a>.</li>
...     </ol>
...
...     </Div>""")
>>> for element in doc.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/ol/li'):
...   print "".join(element.xpath('descendant-or-self::text()'))
...
Central Intelligence Agency.
Culinary Institute of America.
```

Please note that `//` has potentially poor performance / unintended execution and should be avoided where possible, but difficult to do so with the example HTML fragment.