# How to find text beetween html tags by html agility pack C#

Tags: c#, html, text

I dont know how to take this text by Html agility pack...Could you help me

```
<h1>
   <div style="float: right; font-size: 13px;">Text I dont need</div>
    Text I need to take
</h1>
```

I try some thing but I cant...help me plz

Comment: It is called "mixed content" in XML - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618016/html-xpath-extracting-text-mixed-in-with-multiple-tags for samples, more results - http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+xml+text+mixed+content+xpath

Comment: I tried...but I cant find success...plz help me

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking first element of the in the document with tag h1, after that the text `.//text()[2]` of this element.

```
var coll = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "h1").ToList().FirstOrDefault();

string text = coll.SelectNodes(".//text()[2]").FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
```