# Concatenating Xpath nested text in Scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying to concatenate some nested text together with xpath in Scrapy. I think it uses xpath 1.0? I've looked at a bunch of other posts, but nothing seems to get quite what I want

Here is the specific part of the html (actual page http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_episodes):

```
<tr>
<td colspan="5" style="border-bottom: #BCD9E3 3px solid">
    Finn and Princess Bubblegum must protect the <a href="/wiki/Candy_Kingdom" title="Candy Kingdom">Candy Kingdom</a> from a horde of candy zombies they accidentally created.
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" style="border-bottom: #BCD9E3 3px solid">
Finn must travel to <a href="/wiki/Lumpy_Space" title="Lumpy Space">Lumpy Space</a> to find a cure that will save Jake, who was accidentally bitten by <a href="/wiki/Lumpy_Space_Princess" title="Lumpy Space Princess">Lumpy Space Princess</a> at Princess Bubblegum's annual 'Mallow Tea Ceremony.'
</td>
</tr>

(much more stuff here)
```

Here is the result I want back:

```
[u'Finn and Princess Bubblegum must protect the Candy Kingdom from a horde of candy zombies they accidentally
    created.\n', u'Finn must travel to Lumpy Space to find a cure that will save Jake, who was accidentally bitten', (more stuff here)]
```

I've tried using the answer from
[HTML XPath: Extracting text mixed in with multiple tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618016/html-xpath-extracting-text-mixed-in-with-multiple-tags)

```
description =sel.xpath("//table[@class='wikitable']/tr[position()>1]/td[@colspan='5']/parent::tr/td[descendant-or-self::text()]").extract()
```

but this only gets me back

```
[u'<td colspan="5" style="border-bottom: #BCD9E3 3px solid">Finn and Princess Bubblegum must protect the <a href="/wiki/
Candy_Kingdom" title="Candy Kingdom">Candy Kingdom</a> from a horde of candy zombies they accidentally created.\n</td>',
```

The `string()` answer doesn't seem to work for me either... I get back a list of only one entry, and there should be many more.

The closest I've gotten is with:

```
description = sel.xpath("//table[@class='wikitable']/tr[position()>1]/td[@colspan='5']//text()").extract()
```

and this gets me back

```
[u'Finn and Princess Bubblegum must protect the ', u'Candy Kingdom', u' from a horde of candy zombies they accidentally
created.\n', u'Finn must travel to ', u'Lumpy Space', u' to find a cure that will save Jake, who was accidentally bitten, (more stuff here)]
```

Anyone got xpath tips on concatenation?

Thanks!!

Edit: Spider Code

```
class AT_Episode_Detail_Spider_2(Spider):

    name = "ep_detail_2"
    allowed_domains = ["adventuretime.wikia.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_episodes"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)

        description = sel.xpath("//table[@class='wikitable']/tr[position()>1]/td[@colspan='5']//text()").extract()
        print description
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concatenate via `join()` manually:

```
description = " ".join(sel.xpath("//table[@class='wikitable']/tr[position()>1]/td[@colspan='5']//text()").extract())
```

Or using a [`Join()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.Join) processor in conjunction with an [Item Loader](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html).

---

Here is a sample code to get a list of episode descriptions:

```
def parse(self, response):
    description = [" ".join(row.xpath(".//text()[not(ancestor::sup)]").extract())
                   for row in response.xpath("//table[@class='wikitable']/tr[position()>1]/td[@colspan]")]
    print description
```

Comment: `join()` isn't quite what I'm looking for. I should've been a little more specific. Notice how in the data I want to get back, there is more than just one string. I only want to combine the text with other a tags, but not all the text and a tags together. I'll update my html really quick...

Comment: @pyramidface you can and probably should still solve it with `join()`. Except that you may need to iterate over the rows to make a list of descriptions. Can you also post the complete spider code you have so that I can understand the context more? Thanks!

Comment: @pyramidface okay, I've updated the answer including the code for getting a list of descriptions. Is this something you were asking about? Thanks.

Comment: Ahhh this is great! Thanks... but this raises up some questions for me... Can you tell me about how/why you used `response` as opposed to `sel`? I tried printing out a row without the `.` in `.//text()`.. It was pretty crazy lol. What does the `.` do?

Comment: Also... I noticed that the text within the sup (same level as a tags), like [226], is also combined into the final output. How could I ignore sup with the code that you've written? I've got a solution, but not through xpath. Maybe just do some python parsing to remove anything with square brackets.

Comment: @pyramidface You can and should use `response.xpath` directly - this is basically just a shortcut, that saves you at least one line of code. The dot inside the XPath expression makes it relative, working in the current context.