# Extract dates within text which have occasional <b> tags using XPATH

Tags: scrapy

I am using the following xpath in scrapy shell:

hxs.select("(//table[@class='result']//font/span[@class='g'])").extract()
and I get the following result:

[u'  www.bbhouse.lk/administration/preside ... 2012-5-31   - ', u'  www.listeningexpress.com/speeches/**kumar** 2012-5-27   - ', u'  v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNDgwNjc2MzI=.html 2012-5-27   - ', u'  www.kumar**kumar**.com/ 2012-6-10   - ', u'  www.guao.hk/tag/**kumar** 2012-5-26   - ', u'  www.myspace.com/kumar**kumar**/ 2012-5-27   - ']

What I want to extract is only the dates from all these results:
2012-5-31, 2012-5-27 etc.

My problem is the bold tags which occur sometimes in between, so I cant directly use text() function ( another problem being I just want the dates). Please note that I dont want to use re() function like this:
 hxs.select("(//table[@class='result']//font/span[@class='g'])").re(r'\d+') etc.

I want to get to result only using the XPATH. Also, Substring function works only for the 1st result in the result set so, that too didn't work out for me.

I am basically extracting cache date from http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=kumar

Comment: So what is the actual source HTML / URL for the page you are trying to scrape? Would be alot easier to help you out with an XPath when we get that :)

Comment: I specified the URL at the end.

Comment: You'll have a bad time if you're going to try to do this with XPath. A regex on the XPath result would be most easy, since the date format is the same and easy to capture.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406992/how-to-scrap-text-included-between-various-tags-using-scrapy/17407805#17407805

The above link might be of some help to you

Answer (score 0):

If a path can contain subnodes (like `<b>`) and you need text in all of them, use `string`:

```
hxs.select("string(//table[@class='result']//font/span[@class='g'])").extract()
```

Comment: This returns only the text of the 1st item in the list ie. if I have a list of items each with the above problem, string function just returns the text/string of the 1st item in list.

Comment: Sorry, started using `string` function recently myself. I would suggest to do ` for _hxs in hxs.select("//table[@class='result']//font/span[@class='g']"): _hxs.select("string(.)").extract()` or look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6303276/248296