# Xpath get all links with inner text

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to grab a collection of all the links on a page with inner text.

**These are valid cases:**

```
<a>Foo</a>
<a><span>Bar</span></a>
```

**These are invalid cases:**

```
<a></a>
<a><span></span></a>
```

**I have tried:**

`//a[text()]` but this ignores the case with the spans

`//a[not(text()='')]` but this doesn't filter out the empty case

Is there some way to check if the `text()=NULL`?

**Note:**

I know I can use `document.links;` and then filter manually, but I would rather just have one clean expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer made by **@Seanny123** is correct,I would go this way :-

**HTML:**

```
<a>Foo</a>
<a><span>Bar</span></a>
<a></a>
<a><span></span></a>
```

**XPATH:**

```
//a[string()]
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct expression is:

`//a[normalize-space()]`

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378502/xpath-return-all-non-blank-text-nodes-not-descendant-of-a-style-or-script) for enlightening me.

Comment: Why only `normalize-space()` ? This is also working - `//a[string()]`.

Comment: You test it and let me know,if it coorects,then I want it to post as an answer! :)

Comment: Apparently, I was a little bit over-eager on the claim of speed. After further benchmarking I've discovered they are basically indistinguishable, but I still like the `string()` method better because it's more readable.