# XPath to select 1 element if one of two exists

Tags: xpath, import.io

I want to select one element if one out of 2 exist while using this for 2 pages

1st page (price with discount)

```
<div class="price">
  <span class="originalRetailPrice">$2,990.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="price">
      <span class="salePrice">$1,794.00</span>
</div>
```

or 2nd page (only one price)

```
<div class="price">
  $298.00
</div>
```

I have used
 `//span[@class="originalRetailPrice"] | (//div[@class="priceBlock"])[1]` 
but I get the price twice

What I want is to select the first price when it's `class="originalRetailPrice"` or when it's `//div[@class="price"]/text()[1]`

So finally I want to make the selection to work on both pages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `//` to get texts at any level inside `<div class="price">`:

```
//div[@class="price"][1]//text()
```

Result:

```
Text=''
Text='$2,990.00'
Text=''
```

---

And filter the empty texts with: [`text()[normalize-space() and not(ancestor::a | ancestor::script | ancestor::style)]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4378618/1515819)

```
//div[@class="price"][1]//text()[normalize-space() and not(ancestor::a | ancestor::script | ancestor::style)]
```

Result 1st page:

```
Text='$2,990.00'
```

Result 2nd page:

```
Text='$298.00'
```

Comment: Perfect , Thanks alot for the fast answer

Comment: If you swap div block in 1st xml, result wiil be wrong. It's not the answer

Comment: @splash58 this `//div[@class="price"][1]//text()` worked for me , so its an Answer.

Comment: it is your question you may decide on your mind but the condition `when its class="originalRetailPrice"` is absent in answer

Comment: @OP: It may work in particular cases, but it doesn't meet the criteria described in your question, so there are some cases where it will give the wrong answer.

Comment: It looks like the `originalRetailPrice` will always be before the `salePrice`. As the OP said: *what i want is to select the **first** price when its class="originalRetailPrice"*

Comment: hi said *when its class="originalRetailPrice"*. hi didn't say that no divs before

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way :

```
//span[@class="originalRetailPrice"] | //div[@class="price" and not(span[@class="originalRetailPrice"])]/text()[1]
```

The 2nd part (right side of `|`) select `div[@class="price"]` element only if it doesn't have child `span[@class="originalRetailPrice"]`.