# Putting integers into quotes for xpath

Tags: java, xpath

I was debugging someone else's Selenium code.
They had an xpath something like `td['6']`.  This was failing. I used intuition and changed it to `td[6]` which fixed it.  However, `td['6']` did not give an error as I thought it would.  It located an element, but a completely different one than without the quotes.

So it got me to thinking, what does putting the number in quotes, like `td['6']` actually mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`td[predicate]` means:

> return the first `td` node for which predicate is `true`.

Each *non-empty* string returns `true`, so `td['6']` will select first `td` node found in DOM.

`td[6]` is the shorthand for `td[position()=6]` expression which means:

> return `td` which is the sixth child of `td` type."

Comment: thanks. I understood td[6].  Would be bad of me to ask what that meant ;-).  So it definitely was an error the guy made.  Surprised they passed the test.  Actually there were testing whether it was eidtable, which I am guessing td['6'] was not editable so it looked as though the test passed.

Comment: Almost correct answer. Actually `td['6']` will select *every* `td` child, not just the first. In some contexts when you select several nodes, all but the first are ignored, but in general this isn't the case, for example `count(td['6'])` will return the same result as `count(child::td)`.

Comment: @MichaelKay , yep, but as OP  has mentioned Selenium I assumed that OP is using `findElement` method that can select *single element only (the first found)*

Comment: @JaSON Sounds like you, like the OP, are someone who's strong on intuition. I'm not.

Answer (score 3):

The XPath 1.0 Specification states that ’td’ is the **axis**  (e.g. children) and **node-test** (tag name TD) an everything inside the square brackets is a [predicate-expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-PredicateExpr) which is either **evaluated as boolean** (true or false) or in special-case of a **number evaluated as positional filter** of the node-set:

> if the result is not a number, then the result will be converted as if by a call to the boolean function. Thus a location path para[3] is equivalent to para[position()=3].

### Explained by Example

Following 3 *XPath predicate* cases are explained by evaluating on input from this [sample table (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro):

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
|           Company             |     Contact       | Country |
+-------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
| Alfreds Futterkiste           | Maria Anders      | Germany |
| Centro comercial Moctezuma    | Francisco Chang   | Mexico  |
| Ernst Handel                  | Roland Mendel     | Austria |
| Island Trading                | Helen Bennett     | UK      |
| Laughing Bacchus Winecellars  | Yoshi Tannamuri   | Canada  |
| Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti  | Giovanni Rovelli  | Italy   |
+-------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
```

#### case 1: number as predicate

`td[6]` selects the 6th child table-data element since number `6` is evaluated as shorthand for predicate `position()=6`.

**Example:** select each cell of the the third column

XPath: `//td[3]`

Output:

```xml
  <td>Germany</td>  
  <td>Mexico</td>  
  <td>Austria</td>  
  <td>UK</td>  
  <td>Canada</td>  
  <td>Italy</td>
```

Try [online demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/19da74d4b89320ca1112f3f83ee1b4ae)

#### case 2: quoted string as predicate

`td['6']` selects every child table-data element since the string `'6'` is not-empty or has non-zero length and thus evaluates to `true` (see  [boolean-conversion](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-boolean)). So node-set of TD-elements is not further filtered (because predicate is always true).

**Example:** select each cell (because the string-predicate is always true)

XPath: `//td['3']`

Output:

```xml
  <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>  
  <td>Maria Anders</td>  
  <td>Germany</td>  
  <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>  
  <td>Francisco Chang</td>  
  <td>Mexico</td>  
  <td>Ernst Handel</td>  
  <td>Roland Mendel</td>  
  <td>Austria</td>  
  <td>Island Trading</td>  
  <td>Helen Bennett</td>  
  <td>UK</td>  
  <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>  
  <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>  
  <td>Canada</td>  
  <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>  
  <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>  
  <td>Italy</td>
```

Try [online demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/dfb827d0f4b0765bf7c573fbc8d3db73)

#### case 3: conditional predicate testing the elements

This is the real benefit of *predicate expression* and allows you to test on the elements, for example find all merged table-cells with `colspan` attribute:

```
td[@colspan]
```

See this sophisticated use-case:
[Xpath expression with multiple predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568713/xpath-expression-with-multiple-predicates)

**Example:** select all cells where contents starts with 'A'

XPath: `//tr/td[starts-with(., 'A')]`

Output:

```xml
  <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>  
  <td>Austria</td>
```

Try [online demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/577e2a1797134e89785a0e9be1dc3b59)

Comment: This confuses me.  What else could it be?  "a number is true if and only if it is neither positive or negative zero nor NaN"

Comment: @Tony the "_positive or negative zero_" is mathematical language for 0 [as discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997294/how-is-it-true-that-zero-is-neither-a-positive-number-nor-a-negative-number). The other "_NaN_" means _not-a-number_. [MSDN explaines better in this question similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/346227). Still or even more confused now?

Comment: I thought they just forgot a comma.  It is not positive, or negative, or zero or NAN.  Better "positivie zero, negative zero, or NaN"

Comment: Is there any time it makes sense to put a predicate inside []?  I haven't found any way to use variables in xpaths?  Or do you do something like td['td[5]'] and it is true only if td has a 5th element?

Comment: @Tony Glad you asked :) The square brackets `[]` __is the predicate__, everything inside them the (predicate-) _expression_. To check if something exists use [XPath's _boolean-function_ with your _node-selector_ as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689966/how-to-check-if-an-element-exists-in-the-xml-using-xpath). So  `boolean(td[5])` checks if 5th table-data cell exists.

Comment: @Tony you asked when `it makes sense to put a predicate inside []`. Updated my answer with _case 3_